# Insert my chatbot in a website

Tags: python, chatbot, web-chat

i have a question for you,

i have built a bot in python and i need to know if there is a way (or a service with REST API) to embed it in a website. I dont want to use slack/telegram/facebook messanger and others as comunication channels. I want to use a chat environment in a website but i dont really want to write it myself I've tried to ask for services like LiveChat, Chatlio and Tawk but the support says that there is no API for that. I was thinking of building my own chat but this would take tons of time. It would be very nice to add the functionality that if the bot cant answer the question, a human agent can answer for it.

From where can i start? Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use a chatbot generator

**[bubl](https://dev.bubl.es/)** is a service for designing and publishing a chatbot in minutes. I'm pretty sure it can suit your basic needs.

It can help you:

- define your bot behaviors (its logic) using the [BotML](https://codename.co/botml/) syntax ;
- generate a ready-to-use bot that relies on said behaviors ;
- embed it on a website with a one-liner JS code.

*Note: author here*

Comment: @ArnaudLeymet hatch link is broken

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Talkus](http://talkus.io) and write a slack bot.
Talkus provides a hook that will be called when a visitor starts a conversation.
So when the hook is called, make your bot join the channel and it will be able to discuss with your website visitors.

For the bot, you can use [botkit](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit). It will be easier. Otherwise you can use the slack client https://github.com/slackhq/node-slack-sdk

I hope it will help you.